# Getting the number of files in a folder in java

Tags: java, file, browser

I'm making a basic file browser and want to know how to get the number of files in any given directory (necessary for the `for` loops that add the files to the tree and table)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

From javadocs:

- http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html

You can use:

```
new File("/path/to/folder").listFiles().length
```

Comment: Note that `listFiles()` excludes certain entries.  The javadoc says *"pathnames denoting the directory itself and the directory's parent directory are not included in the result."*

Comment: Fortunately, that matches most people's expectations (although it differs from, say, `ls`)

Comment: In case it's not obvious... listFiles() is allocating an array and populating it with a File instance for every file in the directory.  You might want to be careful using this method if the directory can potentially have a huge number of files.

Answer (score 5):

`new File(<directory path>).listFiles().length`

Answer (score 3):

as for java 7 :

```
/**
 * Returns amount of files in the folder
 *
 * @param dir is path to target directory
 *
 * @throws NotDirectoryException if target {@code dir} is not Directory
 * @throws IOException if has some problems on opening DirectoryStream
 */
public static int getFilesCount(Path dir) throws IOException, NotDirectoryException {
    int c = 0;
    if(Files.isDirectory(dir)) {
        try(DirectoryStream<Path> files = Files.newDirectoryStream(dir)) {
            for(Path file : files) {
                if(Files.isRegularFile(file) || Files.isSymbolicLink(file)) {
                    // symbolic link also looks like file
                    c++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else
        throw new NotDirectoryException(dir + " is not directory");

    return c;
}
```

Comment: how is this better from the other answers?

Comment: This misuses `NoSuchFieldException`. That is supposed to mean that a class or object doesn't have a particular field (variable/constant) within it.

Comment: For different versions of jdk have different ways how to get the number of files in a folder.

Comment: as far as I know, the above methods work fine in Java 7

Comment: Yes, but in my mind, it's better to use new way if it's possible, because the new API covers an old holes. 
That's what this says [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles().
I don't know why the usefull function getFilesCount() do not included into NIO.2, that's why I am using my own implementation.

Comment: wait, what? You never mentioned NIO 2. What is that? How does your implementation address it? Why isn't it mentioned in your answer?

Comment: look into [NIO.2 tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileio.html) because the Java implementation of file I/O has been completely re-architected in the Java SE 7 release. [map from the old NIO API to the new NIO.2 API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/legacy.html#mapping)

Comment: You still haven't said how your technique is any better than that of the accepted answer. Please update your answer with all relevant information as to why you think such a complex piece of code is required